# How to display items in a row of 4 across using Django, HTML, and Python

Tags: python, html, django

This is my code. I want the items to be displayed horizontally. I've tried changing the `col-md-3` and still no luck.

```
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            {% for product in product_objects %}
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="{{ product.image }}" class="card-img-top">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="card-title">
                            {{ product.title }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-text">
                        {{ product.price }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>   
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it's showing it correctly, but I changed:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="column">
```

to:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
```

Now it's displaying correctly.